# PlayFramework получение фильтрованных данных с бд

Tags: java, playframework

Делаю сайт на Play и столкнулся с проблемой, надо получить фильтрованные данные с базы данных. В инет ничего толкового найти не могу, может кто-то знает, как или где описано есть?

**Обновление**

Есть БД есть фреймворк, какой функцией получить фильтрованные данные из БД?
для аналогии в `hibernate` используется аннотация `@Filter`.

Comment: У вас там JDBC, EBean или JPA?

Comment: Я использую EBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search by id

```
LibraryModel libraryModels;
libraryModels = Ebean.find(LibraryModel.class, 7);
```

get all

```
List<LibraryModel> models = Ebean.find(LibraryModel.class).findList();
```

filter

```
Login extends Model{
    ...
    public static Finder<Integer,Login> find = new Finder<Integer,Login>(Integer.class, Login.class); 
    ...
}
List<Login> loginList = Login.find.where().like("login","%test%").findList();
List<Login> loginList = Login.find.where().eq("role","administrator").findList();
List<Login> loginList = Login.find.where().between("suma",number1,number2);
List<Book> tasks = Book.find.where().ilike("name", "%java%").orderBy("name asc").findPagingList(25).getPage(1);
```